# Cypress Assertion error: found text but it saying it did not find it

Tags: cypress

getting this error on my test and It makes no sense at all

AssertionError
Timed out retrying after 15000ms: expected '<ng-bind-html.ng-binding>' to have text 'You don't have any saved items.', but the text was 'You don’t have any saved items.'

Comment: How about if you make the assertion something like `.should('contain.text', 'You don’t have any saved items.')`?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the condition syntax. For such conditions, every symbol counts. You either should copy-paste the text from the actual element, or add a selector to assert the element by selector for future cases

[image]

Comment: thank you. I did not notice the difference there